# google app engine deploy fail

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

```
2013-11-21 17:26:21 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=denashitug', '--passin', 'update', 'C:\\wamp\\www\\sems']"
05:26 PM Application: gcdc2013-sems; version: 1
05:26 PM Host: appengine.google.com
05:26 PM 
Starting update of app: gcdc2013-sems, version: 1
05:26 PM Getting current resource limits.
Password for denashitug: 05:26 PM Scanning files on local disk.
2013-11-21 17:26:30,438 ERROR appcfg.py:1656 Invalid character in filename: images/userprofile/cartoon (1).jpg 
2013-11-21 17:26:30,438 ERROR appcfg.py:1656 Invalid character in filename: images/userprofile/cartoon (2).jpg 
2013-11-21 17:26:30,479 ERROR appcfg.py:1656 Invalid character in filename: images/gallery/cartoon (1).jpg 
2013-11-21 17:26:30,480 ERROR appcfg.py:1656 Invalid character in filename: images/gallery/computer (1).jpg 
Error 409: --- begin server output ---
Another transaction by user denashitug is already in progress for app: s~gcdc2013-sems, version: 1. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".
--- end server output ---
2013-11-21 17:26:32 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

I tried using a solution that was recently posted, but I still have same problem what should I do? It says that the application does not contain an `app.yaml` file, so now what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have previously aborted an update of your AppEngine app.

Before you can update it again, you first need to rollback that partial update. To do this run the command as it says.

```
appcgy.py rollback .
```